# How to make shell script to not create subprocess and don't wait for child execution

Tags: shell-script

If I call a shell script (inner.sh) inside another shell script (main.sh), the first script (main.sh) will wait the end of inner.sh before continue. If inner.sh fails, main.sh fails too.

Eg:

```
cat .main.sh
#!/bin/bash 
bin/bash .inner.sh
```

main.sh will end only after inner.sh ends.

How do I run inner.sh in a separated process (not subprocess, not same process and not in parallel with main.sh)?

What I want to do is make main.sh continue execution no matter what happens with inner.sh.

Comment: `/bin/bash .inner.sh &` or `nohup /bin/bash .inner.sh &`

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut I feel stupid now for not remembering nohup command. I usually use nohup in bash, did not occur to me use inside a script. Thanks

Comment: GypsyCosmonaut. write as answer and I will mark as solved.

Comment: So by “not … parallel from main.sh”, you mean “in parallel with main.sh”? Your question is hard to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/bin/bash .inner.sh &`

runs `.inner.sh` as a subprocess but `.inner.sh` would still be a part of the process of `.main.sh`

but if you want to run `.inner.sh` as a completely detached process then you might want to do

`/bin/bash .inner.sh & disown`

or

`nohup /bin/bash .inner.sh &`

These run `.inner.sh` as a completely separate process. so even if you `^C` out of your `.main.sh`, your `.inner.sh` would still run (given that you do `^C` after the interpreter executed the `disown` or `nohup`).

Comment: Can also run as subprocess if put the command between (). (/bin/bash .inner.sh)